# Why can't I make an NSOpenPanel as key window?

Tags: cocoa, window, panel

Here is the code.

```
NSOpenPanel *panel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
......
[panel runModal];
[panel makeKeyWindow];
```

But it doesn't work, I don't know what is going wrong.Here is the screenshot.

[image]

After I click the panel to make it keywindow manually, it shows like this:

[image]

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?  What happens?

Comment: It means the panel did not become key window after makeKeyWindow called.

Comment: How do you know it's not the key window?

Comment: From the trafficlight status, and titlebar status.

Comment: Well, you've stumped me, but I can tell you this: `[panel runModal]` doesn't normally return until the panel is dismissed, so your call  to `[panel makeKeyWindow]` shouldn't work anyway.  Test this by calling `NSLog` after `[panel runModal]`.  My test app doesn't log anything until I close the panel.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5302/discussion-between-li-fumin-and-rob-mayoff)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to rob mayoff.

Now I put

`[NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];`

right after

`[openPanel beginSheetModalForWindow: nil completionHandler: ^(NSInteger result){......}];`

Everything works like a charm.